# ROS noetic: I want to use GNSS data in Rvis, but an error occurs in the catkin build

Tags: ros, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### First

I started studying ROS about a week ago. I started learning ROS about a week ago. I apologize if this question is elementary. I have git cloned a package that I want to use in ROS, but when I do a catkin build, I get a build error. If anyone has a solution, please let me know.

##Environment##

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS noetic
- GNSS receiver module : ZED-F9P

##Final Goal##
I want to reflect GNSS data in ROS Rvis and use it for autonomous movement of the robot.

##Current problem##
We performed the procedure with reference to the following site.

Reference site: https://qiita.com/k-koh/items/91d7ea55cbdfc3d3aaf9

Procedure

- ~/catkin_ws/src
- git clone https://github.com/hakuturu583/gps_rviz_plugin.git
- cd ../
- catkin build

I got the following error when I did a catkin build.

error message:

> /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/gps_rviz_plugin/src/overlay_gps_display.cpp:55:33: error: ‘PyString_FromString’ was not
> declared in this scope; did you mean ‘PyLong_FromString’?

> 55 |     PyObject* request_url_str = PyString_FromString(request_url.c_str());

> PyString_FromString --> PyLong_FromString

I tried changing line 55 in overlay_gps_display according to the error message, but when I run build again, I got the following error when I did a catkin build.

> Errors     << gps_rviz_plugin:make /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/logs/gps_rviz_plugin/build.make.003.log
> /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/gps_rviz_plugin/src/overlay_gps_display.cpp: In member function ‘bool gps_rviz_plugin::OverlayGpsDisplay::download_map(std::string)’:

> /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/gps_rviz_plugin/src/overlay_gps_display.cpp:55:70: error: too few arguments to function ‘PyObject* PyLong_FromString(const char*, char**, int)’

> 55 |     PyObject* request_url_str = PyLong_FromString(request_url.c_str());

> ```
>   |                                                          ^
> ```

> In file included from /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h:98,

> ```
>              from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/gps_rviz_plugin/include/overlay_gps_display.h:42,
> ```

> ```
>              from /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/gps_rviz_plugin/src/overlay_gps_display.cpp:1:
> ```

> /usr/include/python3.8/longobject.h:103:24: note: declared here

> 103 | PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyLong_FromString(const char *, char **, int);

> ```
>   |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gps_rviz_plugin.dir/build.make:76:

> CMakeFiles/gps_rviz_plugin.dir/src/overlay_gps_display.cpp.o] error 1

> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:211: CMakeFiles/gps_rviz_plugin.dir/all] error 2

> make: *** [Makefile:141: all] error 2

※The following has been resolved

Also, I have performed the procedure with reference to the following site.

Reference site: https://qiita.com/k-koh/items/8fd8ef6310e4f40fa536

Procedure

- ~/catkin_ws/src
- git clone https://github.com/KumarRobotics/ublox.git
- cd ../
- catkin build

I got the following error when I did a catkin build.

> Cmake Error at /opt//ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package)

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rtcm_msgs" with any of the following names:

> rtcm_msgsConfig.cmake

> rtcm?_msgs-config.cmake

> Add the installation prefix of "rtcm_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "rtcm_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "rtcm_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

> Call Stack (most recent call first):

> CmakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)

My guess is that it is due to my ROS version being different from the reference site. Is there any way to make GNSS data available in Rviz?

##At the end##
I am new to ROS, so I am not very good at asking questions, but I intend to learn more. I hope you can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405072/ros-noetic:-i-want-to-use-gnss-data-in-rvis,-but-an-error-occurs-in-the-catkin-build./) by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are multiple questions asked in this question. In general, asking only one question in a post is advised to keep it cleaner and simpler. Nevermind.

**1. 'PyString_FeomString' was not declared**

> error: 'PyString_FeomString' was not declared in this scops: did you mean 'PyLong_FeomString'

It seems that the code is edited. Note that the incorrect "PyString_F**e**omString" (r is replaced by e) by mistake.

- Please correct it and try again.
- As you are using Ubuntu 20.04, I am doubtful about `PyString_FromString` , because the [PyString_FromString doesn't work in Python3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48849047). The workaround is to use `PyUnicode_FromString`, which is given [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_FromString).

**2. "rtcm_msgs" not found**

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rtcm_msgs" with any of the following names:

The package [ublox/ublox_gps](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/ublox/tree/master/ublox_gps) uses `rtcm_msgs`, which has been mentioned in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/ublox/blob/7f592601166d9ddc2e96ad6d986d449e11ce6561/ublox_gps/CMakeLists.txt#L10) file. Furthermore, you are receiving an error because you do not have `rtcm_msgs` installed in your machine. Please install it using `apt` as shown below:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-rtcm-msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-08-17**:
Hi Mr.Ravi Joshi.
Thanks for replying. Also sorry for the delay in replying to you.

First of all, regarding the error 'PyString_FeomString' in the question you posted, this is my typing error.
The correct name is 'PyString_FromString'.
This mistake is due to the fact that I 'typed' the error statement that occurred, instead of 'copy and pasting' it.
My sincere apologies.
I will correct it in the question text.

I would like to correct the error statement that occurred when I executed 'catkin build' after replacing 'PyString_FromString' with 'PyLong_FromString' in the question text.

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-08-17**:
Next, thanks to your advice about "rtcm_msgs", I was able to solve it.

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-rtcm-msgs
sudo apt install ros-noetic-nmea-msgs
```

By running the above two, I was able to run the 'catkin build'. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-08-17**:
In summary, what I currently do not know is about build-error after replacing "PyString_FromString" with "PyLong_FromString".
I do not know what is causing the error or how to deal with it to make it usable.

> error: too few arguments to function ‘PyObject* PyLong_FromString(const char, char*, int)’

What factor should I increase?

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-17**:\

1. You needed to install `ros-noetic-nmea-msgs` because it is mentioned as a dependency in  the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/ublox/blob/7f592601166d9ddc2e96ad6d986d449e11ce6561/ublox_gps/CMakeLists.txt#L11) file. I am glad to could do it successfully.
2. I guess that you need to replace `PyString_FromString` with `PyUnicode_FromString`. Please see a proper explanation in the answer above.

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-08-18**:
Thanks for your reply.

Thanks to you I was able to do the 'catkin build'.

Also, I was wrong about the 'Unicode' thing.
I would like to deepen my understanding of 'PyUnicode' again.

Finally, thank you very much for your detailed answer to my beginner's question.
I will try my best to acquire more knowledge about ROS and grow up to be like you.